# string Iteration delay by 200ms

Tags: c++

Someone can tell me what is wrong with this code?

I want to show 'a' with 200ms delay 
eg.  number 3 will show after 200ms 
numbers 2 and 1 the same, but I can't write correct code to do this.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int a=3;
    do {
        cout<<a<<endl;
        a-=1;
        string tekst = a;
        for (int i = 0; i < tekst.length(); i++) { // Czasowe pokazanie napisu//
            cout << tekst[i];
            cout << tekst[i];
            Sleep(200);       
        }
    }
    while (a=1);
    getch();
}
```

Comment: Do you mean to change the value of `a` in your condition for the `while` loop? `a=1` _assigns_ the value `1` to `a`, and will _always_ evaluate to `true`.

Comment: I dont quite understand how the output should look and what it looks like right now. Can you update the question?

Comment: `string tekst = a;` doesn't to what you probably expect it to do. Why not simply output `a` directly, as in `cout << a`?

Comment: You can't assign an `int` directly to a `std::string`, you need to convert it, such as with `std::to_string()`: `string tekst = to_string(a);` And `(a=1)` needs to be `(a==1)`, but note that `a` will be 2 when the `while` is reached for the first time, breaking the loop. So you may as well just get rid of the `while` loop altogether since it is useless.

Comment: Take out your `Sleep(200)` function call. Does the code run as expected? (It doesn't). Fix the code until the functionality is all there before considering adding the delay.

Comment: What is the problem you are experiencing? You forgot to say.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to show 'a' with 200ms delay eg. number 3 will show after 200ms numbers 2 and 1 the same, but I can't write correct code to do this.

In that case, your `Sleep` is misplaced since it's placed *after* printing. You also do not need to convert the `int` to a `std::string` before printing it. `int`s are perfectly streamable out of the box.

Your `do-while` loop is also wrong. `while (a=1);` assigns the value `1` to `a` so the loop will go on forever since `1` will be implicitly converted to `true`.

A portable way to sleep 200 ms would be using the `std::this_thread::sleep_for()` function instead of `Sleep()` which is not a standard function.

It could look like this:

```
#include <chrono>    // std::chrono::milliseconds
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>    // std::this_thread::sleep_for

using namespace std::chrono_literals;

int main() {
    for(int a=3; a>0; --a) {
        // sleep for 200 ms, the standard way
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(200ms);

        std::cout << a << std::flush;
        // or: std::cout << a << '\n';
    }
}
```

Update for old versions of Dev C++ that doesn't support `<thread>` and `<chrono>`:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    for(int a=3; a>0; --a) {
        Sleep(200);

        std::cout << a << std::flush;
        // or: std::cout << a << '\n';
    }
}
```

Comment: @HoesMad Both `<thread>` and `<chrono>` has been in the C++ standard since C++11 and if you are using C++03, C++98 or even pre C++98 I think that should have been mentioned in the question. What makes you use such an old environment?

Comment: Dev C++ seems like a dead end but in [the Orwell fork](http://orwelldevcpp.blogspot.com/), release 5.7.1, C++11 support was apparently added. The current release is 5.11 (from 27 April 2015). Do yourself a favour and use a modern environment or upgrade Dev C++ to the latest version at least.

Comment: @HoesMad I updated the answer with something that should work in your version of Dev C++.